# How to use interface as type of object?

Tags: typescript

if u see the code. to make argument accept json object. it need define with type built-in typescript data type. how to pass interface as type for json object? it keep repetitive in my code. to make duplicate what implement in interface.

```
interface Credential {
  username: string,
  password: string
};

type Credentials = {
  username: string,
  password: string
}

class User {
  username: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(credential: Credentials) {
    this.username = credential.username;
    this.password = credential.password
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having hard time understanding your question, what do you mean by "JSON object" ???, JSON is _string_ version of an Object thats it.
Interfaces are Object too.

Comment: @bogdanoff i want to pass interface as object type checking. if i pass interface to parameter. that argument will act as array not object. so for this, i keep duplicate interface implement into type. `credential: Credential`

Comment: "act as array not object" --  where is Array ?, your code doesn't even use array datatype anywhere. [ts-playground-sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJQgEwuYcA2yA3gFDLICuAztCHALYQBcyVYUoA5gDRnIAOcKlQDuAeyiYWbDiE4kAvgG4SJMAE9+KdFhxg8+KsgC8xPtVoNmrdl17lBw8ZOm25i1QnxCjAVRpQZuQWUHSMrrKcKg4+zlI2kSp8CGIgMhQIYBIAFAgY2LgELDoF+gRUAJRB5MhgABbAVAB0IWEopnm6hfgtAW3RNfWNTY6iEpgmyJ2lBiOx43wKHp6pbJQBk8ggECLI-tDZROuW4cgA5FBw6mfcAvMu5yli+AD6o3FnyAoVK2nPEE18GJONkQj9VEA)

Comment: @bogdanoff sory2, it return undefined if pass interface. ok back to question. how to pass interface as object for type checking? or it cant?

Comment: I'm afraid the question doesn't make a lot of sense.  Could you find someone to help you with writing in English?

Comment: Something does not make sense here. Interface and type acts the same way in your case.  Both these structures can represent object, so you can use either of them. However don't forget that typescript exists only during compile time, during runtime there is no such thing as typescript interface or type. So if you getting undefined, issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @KiraLT please [check this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJQgEwuYcA2yA3gFDLnICuAztCHALYQBcy1YUoA5gDRkUAHONWoB3APZRMrdpxBcSAXwDcJEgnzDqyAKq0oxfuRp1GLNh26qKyISIlSZl+aqPIE4kLMoIwkgBQIGNi4BKzoWDhgePgAlOSkNjZgABbA1AB0JlD0TMgAvO7BUTFZ+rkQ1knkqekZdmKSmAVFkaH49VoOmFXkimo2XBBgESHRBP7xidXIGGCUOYYzSdkVrLWZq2Z8yzYN3etpmftNbjb950pqHl5gyHCYDKAtIBCiuvr+RFTlZqwA5A8niB-jxbF0mgCGkDQP9kIpYqobtRxPgIBl8OIuP4YSAMkMRsV2pNYkA). i want to pass parameter  as object but with interface type checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are trying to define `Credential` interface that is already provided by global typescript types ([check here](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.credential.html)). Because if this conflict it acts strangely in your case.

I strongly recommend renaming that interface to another name and then you will avoid any conflicts. Rewriting global types with the same name can cause unexpected behaviour. If you rename it, you can just one `interface` without additional type and everything will work.

Comment: ow cause conflict with typescript type. thx man.